# How i compute the properties of G/G/1 QueueingProcess?

Tags: queueing-systems

how can i compute the properties of G/G/1 QueueingProcess using Mathematica using the following distributions

```
QueueProperties[QueueingProcess[ParetoDistribution[k, \[Alpha]], ParetoDistribution[k, \[Alpha]]]]

QueueProperties[QueueingProcess[WeibullDistribution[\[Alpha],\[Beta]], WeibullDistribution[\[Alpha],\[Beta]]]]

QueueProperties[QueueingProcess[ParetoDistribution[k, \[Alpha]], WeibullDistribution[\[Alpha],\[Beta]]]]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What doesn't work in the code you posted?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason the `QueueProperties` `"SummaryTable"` property does not like your `QueueingProcess`.  You many want to report this to WRI.

You can examine your process properties with the following while you wait for an answer from WRI:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   QueueProperties[qp, prop, "Description"],
   QueueProperties[qp, prop]
   }],
 {{prop, "ArrivalRate", "Property"}, propList},
 Initialization :> {
   qp = QueueingProcess[ParetoDistribution[k, \[Alpha]], ParetoDistribution[k, \[Alpha]]];
   propList = QueueProperties[qp, "Properties"];}
 ]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear this code not worked on Mathematica 10.0. Where this code work properly?

Comment: @Amin It should work fine in 10. All of the functions are available in 10.  I ran it in 10.2, 10.3, and 10.4. Try it in a fresh kernel.

Comment: dear following error arises
The first argument QueueingProcess[ParetoDistribution[k,\[Alpha]],ParetoDistribution[k,\[Alpha]],1,\[Infinity],0] is not a valid specification for a queueing process or data. >>

Comment: @Amin I have run the code in version 10.0 and I get the same error.  It appears that the function was improved between version 10.0 and 10.2. However this change is not listed in the New Features guides for either 10.1 or 10.2 in the documentation. It does work in version 10.2 and above.  The screenshot in the post is evidence of this. Upgrade, perhaps?

Comment: Dear thanks, this works on 10.2

Comment: Dear this code compute only Arrival Rate on 10.3 but other properties are not compute able. Anyhow please help how I compute the G/G/1 Queuing Properties?

Comment: @Amin Select the other properties from the "Property" dropdown. Click "ArrivalRate" and select the other properties you want to see.